# Xcopy command with exclude flag still brings excluded file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, xcopy

I want to copy all files/folders except `a.txt` file. The command that I use is like below:
`Xcopy C:\Data C:\NewData /q/s/d/i/h/y/EXCLUDE:C:\Data\a.txt`

This command brings everything including the `a.txt` event though there is exclude flag for it. I am not sure what I am missing. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclude option uses the file provided as a text file that contains the names of files or directories you wish to exclude one per line. So you need something like this:

```
echo a.txt > mylist
xcopy ... /exclude:mylist
```